# Is there a way to debug line by line code written in a view function of django on the website itself?

Tags: python, django

I have a view function in a django application on a webpage that a user himself writes code for (using a framework known to them). After uploading the code, they are redirected to the webpage for which they have written the code for. I want to have a way to visualize line by line the python code that is running on the view function as it gives a clear indication to the user how their code works. Is there a way to debug code on the website itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use print() function.

If you use print() function inside your view then when that view function is executed it prints on Command line or terminal.

in views.py

```
def indexView(request):
    productCat = Product_Cat.objects.order_by('name')
    upcoming = Upcoming_Product.objects.all()
    print(upcoming)
    return render(request,'website/index.html',{'productCat':productCat})
```

in terminal:

```
<QuerySet []>
```

Comment: does that print to the terminal? I want to have debug messages on the webpage itself as the users who write the code for the view function don't have access to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [print()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) function to print the output of your code. Output will be redirected to the terminal.

To check valid attribute of returning object you can also use [dir()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) function along with print().

Comment: I don't want to see it in the terminal but rather on the webpage itself. Do you know a way to do so?

Comment: usng [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) and [django-extension](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions)
django-extension provide you addition management command and much more. these two packages are must and very helpful in debugging process.